# How to "Retrieved from" without date before URL in biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I'm writing a lab report in LaTeX (Overleaf), using the APA style for referencing. I use the biblatex package with the APA style.

However, in my school's reference guide it says to put the words "Retrieved from" in front of a URL which is not required to have a date retrieved, i.e. sources which do not change over time. `apa-biblatex` does not automatically do this, and I can't seem to find a solution which works. The only solution I've found (after at least an hour of googling) is to switch to the package `apacite`, but it would be very tedious to do this.

Below is a magazine article from a database which requires a URL but not the date the information was retrieved.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{DePalma2005,
%Magazine article from electronic database
    author = {DePalma, A.},
    year = {2005},
    title = {Sequencing in the post-genomic age},
    journal = {Bioscience Technology},
    volume = {30},
    number = {4},
    publisher = {Advantage Business Media},
    url = {https://link.gale.com/apps/doc/A132192766/SCIC?u=kungsholmens&sid=SCIC&xid=beac04f2}
}
\end{filecontents}{references.bib}

\parencite{DePalma2005}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This gives me this output, without the "Retrieved from":

[image: Current output]

This is my **desired** output, with the "Retrieved from" in front of the URL:

[image: Desired output]

Do you have any ideas on how this could be solved? It's really bothering me!

Comment: Even though this is a magazine and not a journal, it still seems to be a publication on paper (or at least have the format of a paper-based publication, even if it is online). So strictly speaking it does not need a url I think, because it is already uniquely identifiable based on the article title, magazine title, volume and number (as opposed to a blog post, software documentation website etc. where a url is needed, and an access date as well).

Comment: The linked site looks a bit shady to me on first glance. If I understand correctly, the linked site is not the original publisher of the article. I couldn't find any reliable info in a journal called "Bioscience Technology" and the link at the bottom to http://www.biosciencetechnology.com/ appears to be dead.

Comment: ... I guess what I'm saying is that I would look for a source that looks a bit more reputable than this one.

Comment: @moewe the website is from the publisher [Gale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale_(publisher)), which looks like a legitimate company that maintains publication databases, which contain also publications that they did not publish themselves. I do seem to remember that I have seen booths and PR material from them at scientific conferences that I attended when travel was still allowed.

Comment: @moewe Good thing you're critical of the source, but yes, this magazine article is taken from a scientific database from the publisher Gale which I have access to through my school and have been told is a reliable database by teachers and librarians.

Comment: Ah OK, the fact that the journal home page appears to be dead and that the journal can't really be found anywhere else on the web makes me still a bit uneasy about this article. (I also found it a bit irritating that the article ends with what looks like a list of companies, that makes it look a bit ad-ish.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a change of rules in APA style here. If I understand correctly 6th-edition  APA style wants "Retrieved from" for all URLs and DOIs, whereas 7th-edition APA style only wants "Retrieved from" if you also include an access date (`urldate`).

That is what `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-apa6` implement. (If this is not what the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association* requires, please report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues. It would help if you could include references to the manual and an example document.)

**With `style=apa,` you get the behaviour from the 7th edition of the APA manual** ("retrieved ... from" only with access date [`urldate`])

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{DePalma2005,
  author    = {DePalma, A.},
  year      = {2005},
  title     = {Sequencing in the post-genomic age},
  journal   = {Bioscience Technology},
  volume    = {30},
  number    = {4},
  publisher = {Advantage Business Media},
  url       = {https://link.gale.com/apps/doc/A132192766/SCIC?u=kungsholmens&sid=SCIC&xid=beac04f2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{DePalma2005}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: DePalma, A. (2005). Sequencing in the post-genomic age. Bioscience Technology, 30(4). https://link.gale.com/apps/doc/A132192766/SCIC?u=kungsholmens&sid=SCIC&xid=beac04f2]

**With `style=apa6,` you get the behaviour from the 6th edition of the APA manual** (always "retrieved ... from")

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa6, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{DePalma2005,
  author    = {DePalma, A.},
  year      = {2005},
  title     = {Sequencing in the post-genomic age},
  journal   = {Bioscience Technology},
  volume    = {30},
  number    = {4},
  publisher = {Advantage Business Media},
  url       = {https://link.gale.com/apps/doc/A132192766/SCIC?u=kungsholmens&sid=SCIC&xid=beac04f2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{DePalma2005}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: DePalma, A. (2005). Sequencing in the post-genomic age. Bioscience Technology, 30(4). Retrieved from https://link.gale.com/apps/doc/A132192766/SCIC?u=kungsholmens&sid=SCIC&xid=beac04f2]